# How to separately get user and system environment variables in Windows with C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, environment-variables

I would like to be able to separately query user and system environment variables.
Like they are shown in the `Environment Variables` dialog.

By using the `GetEnvironmentVariable` and `*getenv*` functions I can only get values obtained after merging the two sets of variables, with the user-defined ones taking precedence.
Just like the `set` command shows on the command line.

This capability would be useful to avoid silently falling back on a system-defined variable when a user-defined one with the same name doesn't exist.

Even an undocumented API would be fine.

Comment: Maybe they are in Registry.

Comment: Certainly the location of the system environment variables is clearly documented on MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762275(v=vs.85).aspx) ([`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270(v=vs.85).aspx)) will only use the system variables if you pass a NULL token handle but I don't think there is a function that only gives you the user variables so you have to manually read them from the registry.

Remember that there are two user variable keys in the registry: `Environment` and `Volatile Environment`. The volatile key even has sub keys on some versions of Windows.